# Change text color of bold html text

Tags: android, html, textview, foreground

I want to change text color before displaying it to TextView.
**For example,**
I am getting a text from server like

```
<b>Pratik<b/> has shared photo with <b>you</b>.
```

**Now the requirements are to display `Pratik` and `you` with Bold style and Blue text color.** I tried several ways using `<span>` tag, but I am not getting clear way to display it.

```
String htmlBody = "<b>Pratik<b/> has shared photo with <b>you</b>.";
String formattedBody = "<span>" + htmlBody + "</span><style>b { color: #309ce8 ; } span {font-family: 'Avenir', 'Heavy'; font-size: 17; }</style>";

SpannableString text = new SpannableString(formattedBody);
tvMessage.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE); // This is not working as expected.

tvMessage.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlBody)); // This is not working as expected.
```

Help me achieve that.

Comment: You can try simple <font color=#5FCA1C> tag in your html string and then set as Html.fromHtml

Comment: the string u are getting from server Right? with also <b></b> TAG? 
`<b>Pratik<b/> has shared photo with <b>you</b>.`

Comment: See my post it will help you

Answer (score 9):

```
String htmlBody = "<b style='color:blue !important;'>Pratik</b> has shared photo with <b  style='color:blue !important;'>you</b>.";
```

Comment: Try now, I updated it. It looks like something is overriding this style

Answer (score 3):

Your Solution is:

```
String styledText = "<b><font color='red'>Pratik</font><b/> has shared photo with <b><font color='red'>you</font></b>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like this

```
public void methodName() {
        String html = "Some text <b>here</b>, and some <b>there</b>";
            String result = html.replace("<b>","<font color=\"#ff0000\"><b>").replace("</b>", "</b></font>");
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
    }
```